# Spring mongodb, save document twice: in its own collection and as embedded of other

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have two collections: Foo and Bar. This last one has a relationship hasToMany with Foo. I would like save Foo in one collection and Bar in other but with embedded Foo documents instead of just use a DBRef.

```java
@Document
Foo {
   String title;
}

@Document
Bar {
   String title;
   List<Foo> foos;
}
```

Expected collections:

```js
Foo:
[{ObjectId("5ddad4b73679ca0ecbf3cd4b"), title: "Hello Foo 1", _class: com.play.spring.mongo.Foo},
{ObjectId("34acd4b73679ca0ecbf3cd4b"), title: "Hello Foo 2", _class: com.play.spring.mongo.Foo}]

Bar:
[{ObjectId("asdd4b73679ca0ecbf3cd4b"),
title: "Hello Bar 1" 
foos: [
{ObjectId("5ddad4b73679ca0ecbf3cd4b"), title: "Hello Foo 1", _class: com.play.spring.mongo.Foo},
{ObjectId("34acd4b73679ca0ecbf3cd4b"), title: "Hello Foo 2", _class: com.play.spring.mongo.Foo}
],
_class: com.play.spring.mongo.Bar}]
```

But when I save the Bar document I get this error:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target bean of type java.util.ArrayList is not of type of the persistent entity (com.play.spring.mongo.Foo)!: java.util.ArrayList`

If I remove @Document from Foo, embedded document work on Bar and if @DBRef is added to foos in Bar, then it creates references from Bar to Foo. But with the two annotations @Document it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I created an abstract class Roo and I did Foo inherit from it. In addition I changed Bar so that it contains a list of Roo.

```
@JsonDeserialize(as=Exercise.class)
abstract class Roo {
}

@Document
Foo extends Roo {
   String title;
}

@Document
Bar {
   String title;
   List<Roo> foos;
}
```